# How big is the continuum?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How big is the continuum? If you take $\mathbb{R}$ and take all the naturals from it, you are still at $2^{\aleph_0}$. If you take all the integers, you are still at $2^{\aleph_0}$. If you take all the rationals, you are still $2^{\aleph_0}$. If you take all the algebraic numbers, you haven't even tickled the continuum, and are still at $2^{\aleph_0}$.

It seems that this thing is gigantic, and basically a real monster.

I was wondering, are there any  broader classes of numbers (broader in the sense that are less restrictive in their demands of memberships) that can be "taken" out of the reals and still make it uncountable? What is the "boundary" if such a notion exist? And, is there a way of determining how "big" is the continuum?

Comment: imagine, you can take all negative numbers and there is still a continuum ...

Comment: For all $\epsilon>0$ the interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ still has the cardinality of the continuum.  If fact for all $\epsilon>0$ and all $x\in\Bbb R$, the interval $(x,x+\epsilon)$ has the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: also, you can take out countably many continuums (continua?) and it is still a continuum...

Comment: If you take out the irrationals it is countable.

Comment: The set of computable numbers are an interesting example of a set that properly contains the algebraic numbers but is still countable.

Answer (score 7):

This is a great question, but (understandably) a little unclear - let me address one possible interpretation of it.

**What is the cardinality of the continuum?**

Assuming the axiom of choice, the sizes of sets - the *cardinalities* - have a nice structure: any two sets are comparable (either $\vert A\vert\le \vert B\vert$ or $\vert B\vert<\vert A\vert$), and the set of cardinalities is *well-ordered*. Well-orderedness is a bit technical - what this really means is that the sizes of infinite sets are $$\aleph_0, \aleph_1, \aleph_2, . . ., \aleph_\alpha, . . .$$ with nothing in between (here $\alpha$ is an *ordinal*, so e.g. $\aleph_{\omega^2+\omega\cdot 3+17}$ is a size of infinite set).

What this means is that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$. For instance, maybe $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, that is, there is **no** set of reals which is uncountable but not as large as the continuum! (This is the **continuum hypothesis**.) Or, maybe $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ (this is actually much less ad-hoc than it may seem!). Or perhaps $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\omega$, the "infinityth infinite cardinal". And in this context, we can ask: **can we narrow it down a bit**?

It turns out the answer is, "not much." Specifically, essentially the only thing we can prove in ZFC is that $2^{\aleph_0}$ has *uncountable cofinality*; this is a strengthening of Cantor's diagonal argument, due to Konig, and rules out $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\omega$. However, beyond that practically anything is possible: for instance, it is consistent with ZFC that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega^2+7}$. This was proved by Solovay, and later drastically extended by Easton, building on the discovery of **forcing** by Paul Cohen.

---

Note that this doesn't entirely match the shape of your question. For instance, let's say I ask you "How many reals are left over after I remove continuum many of them?" The answer is, you have no way of knowing! Maybe I removed all of them, or just the interval $(0, 1)$; or all but 17 of them! You may also be interested in other notions of sizes of sets of reals, such as **measure** and **category** (the latter in the sense of Baire category, not in the sense of category theory :P). For example, the **Baire category theorem** implies that if you remove countably many sets, each of which is nowhere dense, then there will still be continuum-many reals left over; and similarly if you remove countably many measure zero (or "null") sets. Questions like "How many null sets can I remove without affecting the cardinality?" can lead you to *cardinal characteristics of the continuum*. But that's another (long) story.

Comment: So does this mean that, assuming the axiom of choice, the continuum has proper subsets of cardinalities spanning up to $\aleph_{\omega^2+6}$? What kind of sets are they?

Comment: @Joshhh No, that's not what it means. It means that it is *possible* that the continuum has such subsets. (Maybe $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, in which case there are *no* subsets of intermediate cardinality.) It turns out, however, that any such intermediate sets would have to be extremely complicated - this can be made precise through *descriptive set theory*. Roughly speaking, any set of reals you can define in a "reasonable" way cannot be of intermediate cardinality! Exactly how strong this can be made depends on whether or not you assume large cardinal axioms, and if so, which ones . . .

Comment: Not only can't we narrow down the size of $\mathbb R$, but *any set* can be generically coded into a real. Even the set of all reals can be coded into a single real and doing so creates a lot of new reals - thereby changing the set of reals... It's weird - and beautiful!